# Simple formula for the $n$-ary version of $(x,y) \mapsto \frac{x+y}{1-xy}$

Tags: summation, fractions, products

Let $x * y = \frac{x + y}{1 - xy}$. I want a single formula for $x_1 * x_2 * \ldots * x_n$, for all natural $n$.

In order to generate plausible candidates, let's see what happens at small values of $n$:

- $x_1 * x_2 * x_3 = \dfrac{x_1 + x_2 + x_3 - x_1x_2x_3}{1 - x_1x_2 - x_1x_3 - x_2x_3}$
- $x_1 * x_2 * x_3 * x_4 = \dfrac{x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 - x_1x_2x_3 - x_1x_2x_4 - x_1x_3x_4 - x_2x_3x_4}{1 - x_1x_2 - x_1x_3 - x_1x_4 - x_2x_3 - x_2x_4 - x_3x_4 + x_1x_2x_3x_4}$

Then I conjecture the following:

$x_1 * x_2 * \ldots * x_n = \dfrac
{\sum_{I \in T_1} \prod_{i \in I} x_i - \sum_{I \in T_3} \prod_{i \in I} x_i}
{\sum_{I \in T_0} \prod_{i \in I} x_i - \sum_{I \in T_2} \prod_{i \in I} x_i}$

Where $T_k = \{\, I \in \wp(\{1, 2 \ldots n\}) : k \equiv |I| \pmod 4 \, \}$

Is there a nice proof of the above not involving transcendental functions?

Comment: $$x*y=\tan(\arctan x+\arctan y)$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: Is there a proof not involving transcendental functions?

Comment: Continuing @labbhattacharjee's brilliant observation
$$
x_1 * x_2 * \cdots * x_n = \tan \left( \arctan x_1 + \arctan x_2 + \cdots  + \arctan x_n \right)
$$

Comment: The suggestion of @labbhattacharjee suggests looking at $\left. \frac{\Im t}{\Re t}\right|_{t = \prod_{j=1}^n (1+ \mathrm{i} x_j)}$.  This just encodes the slopes (tangents) in the components of a complex number.

Comment: @EricTowers: Oooh! Then $t = \sum_{j=0}^n i^j \sum_{K \in S_j} \prod_{k \in K} x_k$, where $S_j = \{ K \in \wp(\{1, 2 \ldots n\}) ~|~ |K| = j \}$, right? Then taking the imaginary and real parts of $t$ is really easy, and they correspond to the numerator and denominator of my original expression, right?

Comment: I edited to try fulfilling your wishes. Feel free to edit again if you don't like it. Also, I changed your set notation to use ":", because usually "|" can be confusing especially if you have absolute value signs or divisibility signs. In any case if you want the original one use `\mid` which spaces nicely.

Comment: @user21820: Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on my comment...

Suppose all the $x_j$ are real.  We proceed by induction.  We write $\frac{\Im}{\Re}(t)$ to represent the ratio of the imaginary to real parts of the complex number $t$.  Then $$\begin{align}
x_1 &= \frac{\Im}{\Re}( (1+\mathrm{i} x_1) ) = x_1 \text{ and }\\
x_1 \ast x_2 &= \frac{\Im}{\Re}( (1+\mathrm{i} x_1)(1+\mathrm{i} x_2) ) = \frac{x_1 + x_2}{1 - x_1 x_2},
\end{align}$$ establishing the result for the smallest allowed $n$.  (Actually, I've assumed this is what you want for $n=1$, since you didn't specify.)  Suppose now $n >2$ and $\ast_{j=1}^{n-1} x_j = \frac{\Im}{\Re}\left( \prod_{j=1}^{n-1} (1 + \mathrm{i}x_j) \right)$.  Then 
$$\begin{align}
    \frac{\Im}{\Re}\left( \prod_{j=1}^{n} (1 + \mathrm{i}x_j) \right)
    &= \frac{\Im \left( (1 + \mathrm{i}x_n) \prod_{j=1}^{n-1} (1 + \mathrm{i}x_j) \right)}{\Re\left( (1 + \mathrm{i}x_n) \prod_{j=1}^{n-1} (1 + \mathrm{i}x_j) \right)} \\
    &= \frac{\Im \left( \prod_{j=1}^{n-1} (1 + \mathrm{i}x_j) \right) + x_n \Re \left( \prod_{j=1}^{n-1} (1 + \mathrm{i}x_j) \right) }{\Re \left( \prod_{j=1}^{n-1} (1 + \mathrm{i}x_j) \right) - x_n \Im \left( \prod_{j=1}^{n-1} (1 + \mathrm{i}x_j) \right)} \\
    &= \frac{ \frac{\Im}{\Re} \left( \prod_{j=1}^{n-1} (1 + \mathrm{i}x_j) \right) + x_n }{1 - x_n \frac{\Im}{\Re} \left( \prod_{j=1}^{n-1} (1 + \mathrm{i}x_j) \right)} \\
    &= \frac{\Im}{\Re} \left( \prod_{j=1}^{n-1} (1 + \mathrm{i}x_j) \right) \ast x_n \\
    &= \left( \ast_{j=1}^{n-1} x_j \right) \ast x_n \\
    &= \ast_{j=1}^{n} x_j.
\end{align}$$  (It's traditional to write this last display in reverse order, but I think the manipulations are easier to follow in this order.)  The step yielding $\dots {} - x_n \Im \dots$ in the denominator may be less than obvious:  we want the negative imaginary part here because (in the previous line) when it is multiplied by $\mathrm{i} x_n$, it must yield a positive real part.  (Trying to stumble across this manipulation in the traditional order is why I think the order above is easier to follow.)  This completes our induction.

Having done that, it should be no great challenge to show that $\frac{\Im}{\Re}\left( \prod_{j=1}^{n} (1 + \mathrm{i}x_j) \right)$ splits the even and odd degree terms into the denominator and numerator, respectively, and also has the signs you want for your $\pmod{4}$ representation.

Comment: $*$ has obvious identity and inverses, commutes just as obviously, and I had already separately proved that it's associative. But it would've never occured to me to represent each $x_j$ by $1 + ix_j$ (or, rather, its equivalence class modulo scaling by a nonzero real). Thanks!

Comment: I think the most progress came from @labbhattacharjee.  I also recognized this as the sum of angles formula for tangent.  Your "split into classes mod 4"  makes me think of the powers of i, or of the [Gaussian integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integers).  (If your formula had been mod 6, I would have thought of the [Eisenstein integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_integer).)  The rest was just figuring out $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in $\alpha + \beta x$ for the multiplicands.